# Simplify access to controller and action in my ruby script

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rest-client

I have a script(script/seed.rb), working with SCV file. I want to use "update_my_controller_name_path" helper instead of "localhost:3000/update". A simple helpers, such as "root_path" and etc. didn't work.
The question is how can I simply get some controller and action, which I want to  request instead of "localhost:3000/update" ?
Here is my code(script/seed.rb):

```
  require 'rest_client'
require 'csv'

  CSV.foreach('data/seed_data.csv', headers: true)  do |row|
     RestClient.get 'localhost:3000/update', :params => {:temp => row['temp'], :hum => row['hum']} 
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `require './config/environment` to the top of your script. This will boot up your rails app, build routes and make the route helpers available for you to use in your script via the url_helpers module:

```
require './config/environment'
Paths = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

Paths.root_path
Paths.update_my_controller_name_path
```

Note: this will slow down your script by a few seconds.

2nd Note: You may need to make it `require '../config/environment'` since your seeds script is not in the rails root.